# jqGrid Multiselect does not retrieve data

Tags: jqgrid, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a problem in my multiselect for the code below. While adding new row when I select all items in the list of  ‘resources’ column (this field is multiselect with checkbox) and save the row, all data of the row saves correctly to the database. But when the same row is retrieved for editing I see all the items of resources selected except the first one. In the above code I am using bootstrap multiselect plugin. But same is the behaviour when I use eric hynds multiselect plugin. This problem appears to be only with the first item in the list.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Maintenance Daily Log</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/jquery-ui.css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 70%;
}
table, th, td {
font-size: 100%;

}
#editmodlist {
font-size: 70%;
}
div#editmodlist {
width: 1000px;
font-size: 130%;

}
.ui-jqgrid {font-size:0.5em;}

div .mce-tinymce {
margin-left: 5px
}
div .mce-btn button, div .mce-menu-item-normal {
font-size: 80%;
}
ul .ui-multiselect-checkboxes {
font-size: 130%;

}
#ui-datepicker-div {
font-size:120%;
}
div .ui-multiselect-header {
font-size: 100%;
}
.ui-multiselect-menu {
font-size: 150%;
width: 100%
}
button .ui-multiselect {
width: 100%;
}
</style>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#list").jqGrid({
url:'server.php',
datatype: "json",
mtype: "POST",
colNames: ["SL","Date", "Shift", "Equipment","Resources-1", "Resources", "Works done", "Spares used", "Status"],
colModel: [
{name:'id',index:'id', width:30,classes: 'cvteste', hidden:true},
{ name:'date',index:'date',search: true,searchoptions: {searchhidden: true},editrules:{date:true,required:true},datefmt:'dd-mm-Y', width:70, sortable:false,classes: 'cvteste',editable:true, editoptions:{size:10, dataInit:function(el){
$(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'});
}
}},
{ name:'shift',index:'shift',search: true,searchoptions: {searchhidden: true}, edittype:'select', formatter:'select', editoptions:{value:"G:G;A:A;B:B;C:C"}, width:35,align:"center",classes: 'cvteste',editable:true },
{name:'equipment',index:'equipment',width:110,classes: 'cvteste',editable:true, search: true,searchoptions: {searchhidden: true},edittype:'select', editoptions:{dataUrl:'equipments.php'}},
{name:"resources-1", index:"resources-1",width:105,sortable:false, editable:false},
{name: 'resources', index: 'resources', width: 105, align: 'left', editable: true, formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', hidden:true, editrules:{edithidden:true}, editoptions: { /*dataUrl: 'resources.php',
postData: function (rowid, value, cmName) {
return {
myId: rowid
}
},*/
dataUrl: function(){
var srow = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
var myUrl = "resources.php";
if( srow ) {
myUrl = 'resources.php?myId='+srow;
}
return myUrl;
},
multiselect:true,
dataInit: function (elem) {
setTimeout(function () {
$(elem).multiselect({
//minWidth: 150, //'auto',
// height: "auto",
// selectedList: 2,
// checkAllText: "all",
// uncheckAllText: "no",
// noneSelectedText: "Any",
/*open: function () {
var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect- menu:visible");
$menu.width("auto");
return;
}*/
});
}, 2000);
},
multiple: true
// defaultValue: 'IN'
}
},
{ name: "workdone", index: "workdone", width: 80, sortable: false, editable: true,
//edittype: "textarea"
edittype:'custom',
editoptions: {
custom_element: function (value, options) {
var elm = $("<textarea></textarea>");
elm.val(value);
// give the editor time to initialize
setTimeout(function () {
//tinymce.remove();
//var ctr = $("#" + options.id).tinymce();
//if (ctr !== null) {
// ctr.remove();
//}
try {
tinymce.remove("#" + options.id);
} catch(ex) {}
tinymce.init({selector: "#" + options.id, plugins: "link"});
}, 50);
return elm;
},
custom_value: function (element, oper, gridval) {
var id;
if (element.length > 0) {
id = element.attr("id");
} else if (typeof element.selector === "string") {
var sels = element.selector.split(" "),
idSel = sels[sels.length - 1];
if (idSel.charAt(0) === "#") {
id = idSel.substring(1);
} else {
return "";
}
}
if (oper === "get") {
return tinymce.get(id).getContent({format: "row"});
} else if (oper === "set") {
if (tinymce.get(id)) {
tinymce.get(id).setContent(gridval);
}
}
}}
},
{name:'sparesused',index:'sparesused',search: true,searchoptions: {searchhidden: true}, width:150, sortable:false,classes: 'cvteste',editable:true, editoptions:{size:100}},
{name:'status',index:'status',width:110,classes: 'cvteste',editable:true, search: true,searchoptions: {searchhidden: true},edittype:'select', editoptions:{dataUrl:'status.php'}}
],
pager: "#pager",
rowNum: 10,
rowList: [10, 20, 30],
sortname: "date",
sortorder: "asc",
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
autoencode: true,
caption: "Maintenane Daily Log",
editurl: "update.php"
});
$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: true, edit:true}, {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:800},{closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:800}
);
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div><table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
<div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my resources.php I have as below

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['myId']))
{
$rowid=$_REQUEST['myId'];
require_once 'config.php';
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT resources FROM worksdata WHERE id=$rowid limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$value = $row['resources'];

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM resources")
or die(mysql_error());
echo "<select multiple='multiple'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

echo '<option value="'.$row['resource'].'"';
if (strpos($value,$row['resource']) !== false)
echo " selected='selected' ";

echo '>';
echo $row['resource'];
echo '</option>';

}
echo "</select>";
}

else
{
require_once 'config.php';
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM resources")
or die(mysql_error());
echo "<select multiple='multiple'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

echo '<option value="'.$row['resource'].'"';
echo '>';
echo $row['resource'];
echo '</option>';

}
echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

What may be the problem here?